# GraphicsMagick fails when using NorthWest gravity

Tags: java, imagemagick, graphicsmagick

I run into something with graphicsmagick that is seemingly a bug, but a very wierd one.

When I execute the following command, it works fine:

```
gm convert /etc/files/background/1.jpg -draw "gravity 'West';fill '#FFFFFF';font 'Courier';font-size 24;rotate 180;translate 5,5 text 0, 0 'preview_title'" /vagrant/output.jpg
```

But if I change the Gravity to NorthWest, it fails with an error: *'gm convert: Non-conforming drawing primitive definition (text) [No such file or directory].'*

```
gm convert /etc/files/background/1.jpg -draw "gravity 'NorthWest';fill '#FFFFFF';font 'Courier';font-size 24;rotate 180;translate 5,5 text 0, 0 'preview_title'" /vagrant/output.jpg
```

However it is not only the Gravity value that has something to do with this error because if I change the transle setting to -5, -5 from 5, 5 then it is working fine again:

```
gm convert /etc/files/background/1.jpg -draw "gravity 'NorthWest';fill '#FFFFFF';font 'Courier';font-size 24;rotate 180;translate -5,-5 text 0, 0 'preview_title'" /vagrant/output.jpg
```

So it seems that the NorthWest gravity value causes an error when compared with specific translate values.

Has anyone run into this error? Is it a bug or does anyone know what is the reason of it?

Comment: You didn't mention your GraphicsMagick version, but I've verified that the behavior is exhibited by the current development version, GraphicsMagick-1.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to finally figure out a solution to this issue.

It is apparently a Graphics Magick bug, because it only happens if part of the text is inside the image but part of it is outside on the X and Y coordinates as well. So for example if the text is completely outside the image, it works well. But if I have a text positioned in Northwest, and use -5 -5 positioning, then it fails with the error.

The solution I used was to create a huge "canvas" that is around 2x larger then the imgage. First I put the image in the center of the canvas, then position the texts over the image. Because now we have a huge canvas, the texts are not falling partly outside the image (because the image for GM is currently the canvas) and GM can handle them. After I positioned all the texts I crop the middle of the image, that is the part which I really need.

An example command I used looks like this:

```
gm convert  -background white -extent 5000x5000-1000-1000  /etc/files/background/1.jpg   -draw "gravity 'NorthWest';fill '#000000';font 'Courier';font-size 22;rotate 0;translate 970,1005 text 0, 0 'prlasdfsdfv'" -crop 1427x1992+1000+1000  /vagrant/output.jpg
```

Comment: The bug has been fixed in GraphicsMagick snapshot 1.4.020141214.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to write the text partly outside the image boundaries.  "SouthEast" with "translate -5,-5" also fails.  The only bug seems to be that the error message is somewhat inscrutable.

EDIT: The bug has been fixed in GraphicsMagick snapshot 1.4.020141214 (no error message is emitted in these circumstances).

Comment: Text can be written outside the image. The problem only arises when I try to write it in a way that part of it is visible, but other part is outside.